# Trying to diagnose a memory leak in Azure ASP.NET Core WebAPI application

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have been chasing this memory leak for about a month now and can't figure it out. The application is running in Azure using .NETCore 2.2 and is a simple WebAPI. In our development environment I decided to write an application that would send thousands of requests to an endpoint on the target app. In total I sent 1,000,000 requests in a 12 hour period until 2:30 AM. This is what the memory stats looked like:

Working Set:
[image: working set]

Private Bytes:
[image: private bytes]

The stats at about 6 hours the program finished:
[image: process stats]

So, the private bytes stayed at where it was and it looks like it's all paged memory, the working set dropped instantly as soon as the program stopped. I decided to dump the memory while the private bytes are sitting where they are and the stats look totally normal. The size of the dump was over 1.4 GB! But what it showed was underwhelming:

[image]

It shows only 10 MB of memory being used by objects. Where is all this memory allocated?

One thing that's interesting is if I let this go eventually it will hang for a while then crash ("CGI application encountered an error..."). The handle count will all of a sudden spike over 10,000, then hang (2 minute request time, cancel request) then crash and shut down forever until a human restarts it.

I have no idea what my next steps should be. I am at a total loss as to what is causing this memory build up. PerfView, dotMemory, Visual Studio shows nothing wrong with managed memory. I run diffs at the start and end, and nothing is strange. Sort of getting desperate at this point.

Comment: `The application is running in Azure using .NETCore 2.2 and is a simple WebAPI`. Make the app "simpler" and run your tests again to see if the leak persists. It may take a while through process of elimination, but certainly far less than 1 month.

Comment: I'll just start a new WebAPI with a simple ping endpoint and then work up from there. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: [Diagnosing Memory Leaks in Azure App Services with PerfView](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/diagnosing-memory-leaks-in-azure-app-services-with-perfview)

Comment: How your investigation went? Did you find the issue?

Comment: No. the problem magically fixed itself. I am thinking it was an issue with the underlying .netcore framework and MS updated the framework to address the issue. Very frustrating to say the least.

Comment: Did you change version targets or anything?  Im having this same issue with a webapi that  just serves up config values to the FE.

Comment: @AdamBezverkov: I did really nothing. It just magically fixed itself. Now, I did increase the instances running of this specific API, so I don't know if that had something to do with it or not. Try increasing your service to 2 or 3 instances and see if it persists. Still running .NETCore 2.2.

Comment: This memory leak was completely irradiated by moving from .NET Core 2.2 to .NET Core 3.1. It must have been an issue with the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This memory leak was completely eradicated by moving from .NET Core 2.2 to .NET Core 3.1. It must have been an issue with the framework.